# Wrapping text around an image

Tags: html, css, text, styling, multiple-columns

I'm having some trouble wrapping text on a web application I'm designing for a client. Below you can see where I am having trouble:

[image: Text wrapping issue]

So ideally I would like this text to wrap underneath the text above it, in a uniform manner. Not underneath the image. Below you can see the HTML code I am using for this:

```
<ul>
    <div class="grid">

        <div class="col-1">

            <li class="howDoPadding">

                <label for="id_delivery_0">

                              <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}rd/images/message_icon.png" class="byAppointment" />

                       <input checked="checked" type="radio" id="id_delivery_0" value="chat" name="delivery" />

                           Answer<div class="lightBlueText">Chat</div> By Appointment (Fastest)


                </label>

            </li><!-- .howDoPadding -->

        </div><!-- .col-1 -->


        <div class="col-1">

            <li>

                <label for="id_delivery_2">

                    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}rd/images/message_fly_right.png" class="mailASAP" />

                    <input type="radio" id="id_delivery_2" value="email" name="delivery" />

                    Answer<div class="lightBlueText">Mail</div> ASAP (Within 1-2 days)

                </label>

            </li>

        </div><!-- .col-1 -->

    </div><!-- .grid -->

</ul>
```

And all of the CSS is below:

```
/* Form */
.col-1 li.howDoPadding { padding-bottom: 10px!important; }

.byAppointment { margin: 0 0 -4px 10px;}

.offlineForm .lightBlueText { 
    color: #80A9BD; 
    display: inline;
}

.mailASAP { margin: 0 0 -4px 18px; }


/* Grid */
*, *:after, *:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

/* Grid Gutters */
[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

[class*='col-']:last-of-type { padding-right: 0; }

.col-1 { width: 100%; }
```

You can also check out a working example of this at: http://jsfiddle.net/Mjs2u/

Thank you very much for any and all help. I really appreciate it! Let me know if you guys need me to elaborate on anything else or you need/want more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code is ill-formed. Forget `ol`, `ul` listing if there isn't a list. `ol` should only have `li` as its children elements. `<ol><div><li></li></div></ol>` is bad practice.

Basically, if you want to put something under sth, you can group them into a `div` or other block element. Do not use `float` layout for the `div` or you will have similar layout as your example if the previous element is shorter than your div.

You can use some flexible layout patterns. Use a wrapper div with a wide `padding-left`, where the image and radio button will be placed. And put the label and text in the main body of the div. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ArieShout/c2eKZ/):

```html
<div class="flexible-layout">
    <div class="left-content">
        Image
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        You text goes here<br />
        Second line goes here
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.flexible-layout {
    padding-left: 80px;
    position: relative;
}
.flexible-layout .left-content {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 80px;
}
</style>
```

For your specific code sample, I made some refactoring based on the content you've given, and you can check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArieShout/WjjBM/) to see if it's what you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain the problem with my code, refactor it, and write it out for me. It was just what I was looking for and I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="offlineForm">
  <ul>
    <li class="howDoPadding">
      <label for="id_delivery_0">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RVmh2rz.png" class="byAppointment" />
      <input checked="checked" type="radio" id="id_delivery_0" value="chat" name="delivery" />
      <div class="label">Answer <span class="lightBlueText">Chat</span> By Appointment (Fastest)</div>
      </label>
    </li>       
    <li>
      <label for="id_delivery_2">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8J0SEVa.png" class="mailASAP" />
      <input type="radio" id="id_delivery_2" value="email" name="delivery" />
      <div class="label">Answer <span class="lightBlueText">Mail</span>ASAP (Within 1-2 days)</div>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>



body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }

ul li { list-style: none; }

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

*, *:after, *:before { box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }

form.offlineForm { width: 200px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 30px; }

label { padding-left: 25px; display: block; position: relative; }

label img { position: absolute; left: -25px; }

label .lightBlueText { color: #80A9BD; }

label div.label { display: inline; }

li.howDoPadding { padding-bottom: 20px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4faQk/

hope it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

try this:

add `span` with `class` name in the text you want to move then `position:relative;`

below i add `<span class="text">`

**html:**

```
<li class="howDoPadding">
  <label for="id_delivery_0">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RVmh2rz.png" class="byAppointment" />
    <input checked="checked" type="radio" id="id_delivery_0" value="chat" name="delivery" />Answer
    <div class="lightBlueText">Chat</div> <span class="text">By Appointment (Fastest)<span>
  </label>
</li>

<li>
  <label for="id_delivery_2">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8J0SEVa.png" class="mailASAP" />
    <input type="radio" id="id_delivery_2" value="email" name="delivery" />Answer
    <div class="lightBlueText">Mail</div> <span class="text">ASAP (Within 1-2 days)</span>
  </label>
</li>
```

**css:**

```
.text {
    position:relative;
    left:15px;
}
```

hope this help you